# Nativescript angular android app is unable to read file from private app folder after copying the file

Tags: android, json, angular, nativescript

I have a simple app in native script angular for android, where I store some user-defined data into a JSON file in the app's private folder.
It actually works, but the problem is, if I copy the file to sd card and then back in the app folder, the app can't read the content of the file. Of course, I changed the permissions of the file to 600 (that's what the original file had). But it still doesn't work.
If you ask why I'm copying the file to sd card and back it's because I'm trying to solve a problem where if I update the app in play store it is unable to read the stored JSON file created by the previous version and I think that it's somehow related.
The code for saving data into file is this:

```
saveUsers() {
        this.adresarAppky = fs.knownFolders.currentApp();
        this.adresarZrodenci = this.adresarAppky.getFolder('zrodenci');
        this.zrodenciFile = this.adresarZrodenci.getFile('zrodenci.json');
        this.zrodenciFile.writeText(JSON.stringify(this.users))
            .then(result => {
                console.log('File saved');
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error saving ' + err);
            })
    }
```

and this is code for reading the file contents

```
loadSavedUsers() {
        this.adresarAppky = fs.knownFolders.currentApp();
        this.adresarZrodenci = this.adresarAppky.getFolder('zrodenci');
        if (!File.exists(path.join(this.adresarZrodenci.path, 'zrodenci.json'))) this.saveUsers();
        this.zrodenciFile = this.adresarZrodenci.getFile('zrodenci.json');
        this.zrodenciFile.readText()
            .then(res => {
                this.zrodenciData = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log('Data read ' + res);
                this.users = this.zrodenciData;
                this.emitSelectedUser();
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error reading file ' + err);
            });

    }
```

The line with console.log('Error reading file') outputs this error - ReadTextTask returns no result.

Comment: Log your error with `console.log('error reading file', err)` this way you will see all information from the error (and not just the string representation). And show us the complete console log from `File saved` until the error. Also look at the logcat when this happens. Might show some related information there

Comment: Poking around the source of nativescript I found the relevant code part. You should see some kind of error log *in the logcat* with the tag `Async`. Relevant class: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/packages/ui-mobile-base/android/widgets/src/main/java/org/nativescript/widgets/Async.java#L669-L726 ; this might also help debugging your original issue

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, changing ```console.log('error reading file', err)``` resulted unfortunately to the same output as before, the logcat suggestion gave this result: 
11-26 20:03:05.989 25366 25438 E Async   : Failed to read file, FileNotFoundException: /data/data/sk.ndrjvvr.mojhoroskop/files/app/zrodenci/zrodenci.json (Permission denied)

Which I don't understand, because the file has the same permissions as the original file and also the same owner. What might the problem be?

Comment: Why store json files on the disk when there are solutions for persisting data in nativescript https://nativescript.org/blog/client-side-storage-in-nativescript-applications/

Comment: Because it's quite a large json (30-40 kB) so SharedPrefs are probably not suitable and database solution seemed like overkill. And simply saving a json file looked like a good idea :(

Comment: When are you writing to the file? Is it at all possible that either the folder/file does not yet exist when you attempt to read from it? The file might also be locked because you still have the file open somewhere else. `saveUsers()` for example works asynchronously and from your example you have no way to wait until it completes.

Comment: Also, it's better for us when you edit your question when adding more information/code and then write a comment on what you added. I would've liked the whole console output within your question. The code where you copy the file and then read it might also be of interest